# PC reboot at boot time

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, power

My PC keep rebooting every time I try to boot on my HDD. No BSOD, nothing. It just shut then reboot.
I can go into bios and change setting, restore default setting or whatever. Nothing work. I have try with a spare hdd I have and it does the same thing.
The advance boot menu is accessible. I can choose safe mode or any other boot method but... it keep rebooting right after 2 second of boot. I barely have time to see windows logo.

**Operating System.**

Windows XP and Windows 7 installed in diferent Phisical Hard Disks

**Hardware Information.**

- Just Basic Stuff
- No Floopy
- No Optical Drive
- No External Graphic Card

Any idea what is doing this and how to fix?

Comment: this is too broad. you mis alot of information. hardware details, os version try to put yourself in the other side and ask for yourself if your question provide enough information, i suggest you to improve.

Comment: OS used? 1 hdd with XP and 1 hdd with win 7. The hdd boot fine on another computer. For the hardware I have disconnect all useless stuff from the motherboard. That mean no graphic card, no floppy, no optical drive. I still have the reboot issue. Could it be the motherboard or the Sata cable? Any idea how to test the motherboard itself?

Comment: you said you haves 2 hard disks, with one give you the problem?

Comment: i think it could be solved with sysprep, but still missing evidence...

Comment: @karel i voted to close since it involves the basic cycle of os boot etc,kindly see my comment at your answer thnx

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 *The advance boot menu is accessible. I can choose safe mode or any other boot method but... it keep rebooting right after 2 second of boot.* I parsed this sentence as meaning it reboots repetitively in safe mode as well as any other boot method and Aaaarrrr commented under my answer and confirmed this, so you can safely retract your close vote unless you have another reason to close vote this question.

Answer (score 1):

The hard drive with Windows XP and the hard drive with Windows 7 both boot OK on another computer, so that points to a hardware issue as a possible cause of your rebooting problem.

Your computer may have a broken RAM stick. When the computer is booting it tries to detect the RAM, and if it fails it sometimes reboots again and once again it tries to detect the all of the installed RAM. If your computer has more than one RAM stick (e.g. 2 x 1GB RAM), try removing one RAM stick at a time to test if one of the RAM sticks is causing the computer to reboot repetitively.

If your computer has only one stick of RAM, check to see if you get any error message indicating a problem with the RAM when the computer is booting. For example:

```
Recovering Lost DRAM Size
```

Comment: AFAIK,the bootloader begins from the ram so if the ram has issue the safe mode should not be visible ,Have a look over here http://askubuntu.com/a/173260/171270

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 According to the question, it also reboots repetitively in safe mode: *The advance boot menu is accessible. I can choose safe mode or any other boot method but... it keep rebooting right after 2 second of boot.*

Comment: Karel is right. I will have to test with another RAM. But just to be sure. Should the RAM also fail randomly while I'm in the bios or in the advance boot menu? Because I can stay for 15 min in the menu or in the bios and nothing happen. I think I will try to boot on UBCD tonight and do some memtest.

Comment: Usually if the RAM is bad the computer will quickly reboot no matter what. It won't hurt to try either running memtest or swapping the RAM however.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though you have a problem with your registry. In order to fix the registry problem, you have to do one of two things.

a) Boot into Windows and fix the problem manually (cannot be done, obviously).

b) Using the Windows recovery disk tools.

Assuming you have Windows 7 (which is the most common OS of windows to have this problem), [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-7-infinite-reboot-loop/) is a guide to solving the problem, and key components of which are listed below.

1. Insert your installation DVD into the optical drive. If you don't have the disk, follow the instructions bulleted below.

   - Go into your advanced boot menu.
2. Select "Repair your computer" and press Enter.
3. Select "Windows 7" and hit Enter.
4. Select "Use recovery tools that can help fix problems with Windows", hit Enter.
5. Select "Startup Repair", and, you guessed it, hit Enter.

If this doesn't automatically fix startup, then follow **these** instructions.

1. Click "View advanced options for system recovery and support" at the bottom of the error message.
2. Click "Command Prompt" in the following pane.
3. Type in "C:" into the console and hit enter.
4. Type in "DIR" and hit enter.

   - You should see common root folders: Program Files, Users, etc.
5. Now type in "CD \windows\system32\config", and, again, hit enter.
6. Repeat step 4.

   - You should now see RegBack, DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, and SYSTEM.
7. Type in "MD mybackup" and hit enter.
8. Enter this command *exactly* as follows: "copy *.* mybackup".
9. Now "CD RegBack" and hit enter.
10. "DIR", then enter (this enter thing is getting tiresome).

    - You should see:

      - DEFAULT, SAM and SECURITY files, each around 262,000 bytes
      - SOFTWARE file, around 26,000,000 bytes
      - SYSTEM file, around 9,900,000 bytes
    - If any of these are 0 bytes, you'll have to find another way that I don't know about to recover the registry files.
11. If you have said files, do this command, again, exactly as follows: "copy *.* .."

    - This will copy the RegBack files to the directory above, replacing the old registry containers.
12. Agree to all the prompts, then type in "exit" and hit enter.
13. Hit "Restart" on the System Recovery Options screen.

This should fix your computer and you'll be putting away all over again.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: All right, I'll add it in really quick. Apologies.

Comment: I have say before that I have try with another hdd. Those regedit fix and boot fix are useless to me... but thanks for trying.

Comment: @Aaaarrrr - Have you actually **tried** the fixes though?